# Neo4j WHERE IN queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm a graph DB relative n00b, have been playing with Neo4j (via Ruby ActiveRecord, but I don't think that's relevant), very much enjoying it but have found some counter-intuitive behaviour.

My problem involves getting some data from the DB, pulling it back to my Ruby code, doing some processing, then making a second query with the set of ids identified by this external processing (it is too complicated to do in the DB).  The result is an ActiveRecord query like

```
Foo.where(foo_id: foo_ids)...
```

which translates to a Cypher query like

```
MATCH (foo:Foo) WHERE foo.foo_id IN [1, 5, ...] ...
```

The set of ids is largish, a few tens of thousands, and I'm finding this query really rather slow.  The `foo_id` has a unique constraint, and my experience in RDBMSs shouts that it shouldn't be.  Is this just a the way things are or am I ignorant of the proper "graphy" way of doing things?

Answer (score 2):

you need to create index on foo_id .
After that , instead of checking in array 
you can unwind that array and match like following

```
UNWIND [1,4,5,.....] as id 
MATCH (foo : Foo{foo_id:id}) 
RETURN foo
```

Comment: Ah, nice -- I think my `foo_id` should already have an index due to the constraint right? (at least when I tried to apply the constraint I get an error on "index already exists", and after deleting the index and adding the constraint, I see an index with "from constraint" in brackets).  Thanks!

Comment: constraints implicitly create indices..so you are fine